# What is a stroboscopic map?

Tags: chaos-theory, non-linear-systems

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to generate a "stroboscopic map" of some orbits of a dynamical system. I have a hard time finding information about exactly what this kind of map is on the Internet and in my course book, but I suspect it might be the same thing as a Poincaré map or a special case of it? Can anyone explain this type of map and how it differs from the Poincaré map?

Comment: I'm not certain, but the term suggests the map, rather than being continuous like a Poincare map would be at discrete intervals in the same sense a ball in flight illuminated by a strobe light.

Comment: How is the Poincaré map continuous at discrete intervals? I thought you get the Poincaré map by plotting the orbit (or "position" of orbit) periodically and this seems quite stroboscopic to me.

Comment: There you go. Perhaps that's what's being asked for. In an ideal sense though the Poincare map is continuous. When we deal with the equations in computation, indeed it is discretized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stroboscopic map is indeed a special case of a Poincaré map for driven systems. The distinguishing feature is that a given phase of the driver’s period is used for mapping (instead of some other marker event like a local maximum or a zero crossing). If, e.g., your driving term is $\sin(t)$, you would obtain the stroboscopic map by regarding the state of the system in intervals of $2π$ time units.

For example from [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Periodic_orbit):

> For a non-autonomous vector field $\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t)$
>   with $f(x,t) = f (x,t+τ)$ for some $0<τ<∞$, the calculation of the stability properties of a periodic orbit with period $T = \frac{p τ}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are integers (see [Arnold tongues](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Arnold_tongues)),
>   can be done by considering a stroboscopic map which takes
>
> $$x(t) \rightarrow x\left(t + \frac{p τ}{q} \right).$$
>
> The stability properties follow from the eigenvalues of this map, as above.